# node js curl vs http.request

Tags: node.js, http, curl, request

I need send a http request to another server. I can do this in two ways:
1) using http.request()
2) using child_process.exec

```
// ... define timeout, data, url
var __exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('curl --max-time ' + timeout + ' -d \'' + data + '\' '  + url, function (error, stdout, stderr) {});
```

In the first case, the minimum execution time is 0.08 seconds.
In the second case - 0.04 seconds

Which problems can appear in case, if i use the second option? Especially in case of high-load on server.

Thanks.

Benchmark1:

```
//...
timeStart = +new Date().getTime();
request = http.request(options, function (result) {
    //...
    result.on('end', function () {
         timeEnd = (+new Date().getTime() - timeStart) / 1000;
         // log timeEnd
    });
});
request.on('error', function (error) {
    timeEnd = (+new Date().getTime() - timeStart) / 1000;
    // log timeEnd
});
request.end();
```

Benchmark2:

```
// ...
timeStart = +new Date().getTime();
exec('curl --max-time ' + timeout + ' -d \'' + data + '\' ' + url, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
     timeEnd = (+new Date().getTime() - timeStart) / 1000;
     // log timeEnd
 });
```

Comment: How are you benchmarking both steps? If you're just comparing the "node mytest.js" vs curl process then it's likely that curl is quicker as it doesn't have to load a complete javascript interpreter into memory etc...

Node is very capable and efficient in sending http requests asynchronously allowing you to do other stuff while you're waiting for a response. 

Personally, I would not dream of calling curl inside a node process, it just doesn't make any sense!

Comment: Probably it won't scale as well, because you start a new thread for each curl instead of staying with the evented approach of node and because you have to move things across the memory for every result.

But you should realy test it.

Comment: @theo Please edit the question with that code so that it is readable.

Comment: I personally use 3) [`request`](https://github.com/mikeal/request)