# Node.js exec with wget

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-interface, wget

I'm trying to download a lot of files using nodejs and the `exec` command, simplified like this:

```
var cmd = 'wget -O output.csv URL';
var child = exec(cmd, function(err) {
  console.log('DONE');
});
```

However, the callback is triggered before the file was actually downloaded through `wget`, leading to a file that contains garbage like '��0O�6D�1n�]v�����#�'. Shouldn't the callback be triggered once wget is done? When running the same command on the command line it takes rougly 5 seconds, since the file has several MB.

Btw: I'm not using the `request` module since it's slower and I ran into emitter listener issues (`EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 listeners added`).

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you're seeing ANSI escape codes. 6D would mean "cursor back 6 characters".. Can you confirm that `wget -O - URL` returns the text you expect?

Comment: Well yeah, try this URL: `http://productdata.zanox.com/exportservice/v1/rest/22791753C32335607.csv\?ticket\=BC4B91472561713FD43BA766542E9240AFDD01B95B123E40B2C0375E3A68C142\&columnDelimiter\=,\&textQualifier\=DoubleQuote\&nullOutputFormat\=NullValue\&dateFormat\=yyyy-MM-dd%27T%27HH:mm:ss:SSS\&decimalSeparator\=period\&id\=\&nb\=\&na\=\&pp\=\&cy\=\&df\=\&ds\=\&mc\=\&zi\=\&ia\=\&im\=\&mn\=\&lk\=\&td\=\&tm\=\&is\=\&sh\=\&sn\=\&pg\=\&po\=\&du\=\&dt\=\&dl\=\&il\=\&cm\=\&ea\=\&x1\=\&x2\=\&x3\=\&bp\=\&bt\=\&gZipCompress\=null`

Comment: I get 409 Conflict on that URL. What do you get?

Comment: Sorry, seems like copy/pasting it broke smth, try this: http://pastebin.com/Mi8x4vY9

Comment: I'm curious why you think the request module A: is slower, and B: is the cause of your "memory leak", and not your misunderstanding of what is going on, and the proper use of the "setMaxListeners" function.  Hint: it might help if you read through the Event emitter documentation.  http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/events.html#events_emitter_setmaxlisteners_n

Comment: Also please see this discussion to help understand why wget may or may not be faster(as if anything could speed up network I/O but a faster network...?), but independent of this, it's still a bad idea to do what you are doing.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939941/node-js-curl-vs-http-request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will involve some debugging.

Can you please try running your script as:

```
var cmd = 'wget -O output.csv URL';
var child = exec(
  cmd,
  function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
    console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
    if (error !== null) {
      console.log('exec error: ' + error);
    }
  }
);
```

It would be interesting to see what stdout and stderr say.

Right, you provided me your `stderr` which said:

```
http://productdata.zanox.com/exportservice/v1/rest/22791753C32335607.csv?ticket=BC4B91472561713FD43BA766542E9240AFDD01B95B123E40B2C0375E3A68C142
```

This URL the command line gets is missing everything after the ampersand (`&` character). This indicates a problem with escaping.

To get around this try replacing `\&` with `\\\&`.

Comment: Thanks, answer is that you need to escape the ampersand. The shell is interpreting the `&` character to mean run the next part in parallel as a separate statement. Try using `\\\&` instead of `\&`.

Comment: Good call! I wrapped the url into quotes, fixes it as well.